# test memory consumption of a java program with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, memory, plugins, monitor

Is there a plugin in `eclipse` that I could use to test who much memory has my just run program cost?

I am thinking there may be a button from the plugin after I run the program, I could click on it, and it shows me a graph of sort of the peak memory consumption of my program just now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I personally like VisualVM ([tutorial](http://java.dzone.com/articles/best-kept-secret-jdk-visualvm)), included with the latest JDK releases.

Comment: I attached the default launcher with VisualVM, It all works well, but if I launch an java code, in the `local` part of VisualVIM shows up an unknown application, and when the code exits, the unknown application disappears also, how can I retain the profiled results of the program that has run in the past?

Comment: Try the [Snapshots](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/snapshots.html).

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Mr. Nobody that VisualVM is nice. The [Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) has some nice features as well.

Answer (score 1):

The ***total used / free memory*** of a program can be obtained in the program via `java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime()`;

The runtime has several methods which relate to the memory. The following coding example demonstrates its usage.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PerformanceTest {
  private static final long MEGABYTE = 1024L * 1024L;

  public static long bytesToMegabytes(long bytes) {
    return bytes / MEGABYTE;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // I assume you will know how to create an object Person yourself...
    List<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100000; i++) {
      list.add(new Person("Jim", "Knopf"));
    }
    // Get the Java runtime
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    // Run the garbage collector
    runtime.gc();
    // Calculate the used memory
    long memory = runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory();
    System.out.println("Used memory is bytes: " + memory);
    System.out.println("Used memory is megabytes: "
        + bytesToMegabytes(memory));
  }
}
```