# setOnMouseClicked not working properly

Tags: java, javafx-8

I've been working on the GUI part of my card game.

What I'm doing is to show a confirmation dialog when the player clicks on one of the card's ImageView.

Things has been working smoothly but there's a bug that I couldn't fix. 
**After repeatedly clicking on the ImageView and closing the alert dialog. The dialog somehow fails to render its body on subsequent calls.**

Is it a bug? Or am I doing things wrongly? This is my first question in stackoverflow, hope I could find help soon. Thanks!

I took away most of the game-logic codes but it may still seem very lengthy:

```
public class Game extends Application implements IGame {
    final Alert confirmationDialog = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
    final Alert errorDialog = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
    Player currentPlayer;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // launch application
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage startStage) throws Exception {
        // initialization
        startStage.setTitle("Welcome to The Card Game");

        ChoiceBox<Integer> choiceBox = new ChoiceBox<Integer>();
        Label promptLabel = new Label("Number of Players:");
        promptLabel.setStyle("-fx-font: 30 Arial");

        choiceBox.getItems().addAll(2, 3, 4);
        choiceBox.setValue(2);
        choiceBox.setStyle("-fx-font: 20 Arial");

        VBox outerLayout = new VBox(50);
        HBox innerLayout = new HBox(30);
        innerLayout.getChildren().addAll(promptLabel, choiceBox);
        innerLayout.setStyle("-fx-alignment: center;");

        Button buttonStart = new Button("START GAME");
        buttonStart.setOnAction(e -> {
            startGame(choiceBox.getValue());
            startStage.close();
        });
        outerLayout.setStyle("-fx-font: 20 Arial; -fx-alignment: center; -fx-padding: 100; -fx-background-color: #993333");
        outerLayout.getChildren().addAll(innerLayout, buttonStart);

        Scene scene = new Scene(outerLayout);
        startStage.setMinWidth(700);
        startStage.setMinHeight(500);
        startStage.setScene(scene);
        startStage.show();
    }       

    void startGame(int numberOfPlayers) {
        // initialize UI components
        showMessage("The game has started.");
        currentPlayer = players[playerIndex];
        getUserSelection();

        gameStage.setTitle("The Card Game");
        Scene scene = new Scene(mainLayout);
        scene.setFill(null);
        gameStage.setScene(scene);
        gameStage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void getUserSelection() {
        showMessage("It is Player " + (playerIndex+1) + "'s turn.");
        playerLabel.setText("Player " + (playerIndex+1));
        if (currentPlayer.isPlayable(pileTop)) {
            counter=0;
            playerHand.getChildren().clear();
            for(int i=0; i<currentPlayer.hand.size(); i++) {
                Card playerCard = currentPlayer.hand.get(i);
                playerHand.getChildren().add(playerCard.imageView);
                playerCard.imageView.setOnMouseClicked(e -> UserSelectionDialog(playerCard));
            }
            playTable.setBottom(playerHand);
        } else {
            counter++;
            if (currentPlayer.hand.size() < 5) {
                showMessage("Player " + (playerIndex+1) + " draws a card.");
                currentPlayer.addCard(stock.remove(stock.size()-1));
                if (stock.isEmpty()) {
                    showMessage("Stock pile is exhausted, shuffling discard pile..");
                    shuffle();
                }
            }
            showMessage("Player " + (playerIndex+1) + " passes the round.");
            if (counter == playerNo) end();
            else {
                nextPlayer();
                getUserSelection();
            }
        }
    }

    void UserSelectionDialog(Card playerCard) {
        confirmationDialog.setTitle("Confirmation Dialog");
        confirmationDialog.setHeaderText("You are about to play the " + playerCard + ".");
        confirmationDialog.setContentText("Confirm playing this card?");
        confirmationDialog.getButtonTypes().setAll(ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.CANCEL);
        Optional<ButtonType> result = confirmationDialog.showAndWait();
        if (result.get() == ButtonType.YES){
            if (playerCard.match(pileTop)) {
                currentPlayer.playCard(playerCard);
                showMessage("Player " + (playerIndex+1) + " discarded " + playerCard);
                pile.add(playerCard);
                pileTop = pile.get(pile.size()-1);
                pilePane.getChildren().add(pileTop.imageView);

                // end game if player's hand is empty
                if (currentPlayer.hand.isEmpty()) end();
                else {
                    nextPlayer();
                    getUserSelection();
                }
            }
            else {
                errorDialog.setTitle("Message");
                errorDialog.setHeaderText("Cannot play this card.");
                errorDialog.setContentText("Your card does not match the rank and suit.");
                errorDialog.showAndWait();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What might be the problem? I tried to solve this myself, but to no avail. :(

I also realize that the **problem comes after a fixed number of mouseClick events**.
I suspect that the Application detaches itself from the program after some time?

The mouse click event **works properly when I'm doing things that are non-GUI**, for example:

```
playerCard.imageView.setOnMouseClicked(e -> System.out.println("TEST"));
```

**However**, even simple **GUI functions such as adding an item into a ListView doesn't work** after a number of events:

```
playerCard.imageView.setOnMouseClicked(e -> listView.add("TEST"));
```

Screenshots:

No problem for the first 10 alerts

[image: No problem for the first 10 alerts]

Alert body becomes blank after that

[image: Alert body becomes blank after that]

---

**EDIT**

It seems to me that there are some problems, might be **memory leaks** that causes the JavaFX UI to hang. As I add more load to the UI components, the UI seem to hang much faster.

i.e: I added another line to set my stage to fullscreen and it causes the UI to hang within 5 seconds into my application.

```
 gameStage.setFullscreen(true);
```

**EDIT 2**

I've tested my application with this method [test memory consumption of a java program with eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869432/test-memory-consumption-of-a-java-program-with-eclipse) and it is showing a constant 80 megabytes memory usage. So memory might not be the cause of this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I couldn't reproduce the problem after probably a restart of the Java Eclipse IDE. Not sure why, but I guess this question is no longer valid.